# NPM start is showing me errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

I had configure my **webpack** but I don't know why my terminal is showing me this error, when I try to run the code **npm start**, how can i solve it please help me.

```
> es6@1.0.0 start /home/islam/Documents/react-redux-learning/es6
> webpack-dev-server

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-cli/bin/config-yargs'
Require stack:
- /home/islam/Documents/react-redux-learning/es6/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:687:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:903:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/islam/Documents/react-redux-learning/es6/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js:65:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/home/islam/Documents/react-redux-learning/es6/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js'
  ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! es6@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the es6@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/islam/.npm/_logs/2021-01-14T13_52_14_874Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Delete Your Node Module Complete Folder. Then Run Command "npm install". Then again run command "npm start". Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import to your project the `'webpack-cli/bin/config-yargs'` dependency.

Comment: how can i import this dependency 'webpack-cli/bin/config-yargs'

Comment: @BarbieDoll Seems you're using webpack-cli v4, try to update your `start` script from `webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot` to `webpack serve` You can check this issue https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/2424 on webpack-dev-server for more. If my reply help you, please mark it as the awnser :-).